# No puedo recargar la página me lo hace dentro del div contenido

Tags: php

```html
PAGINA PRINCIPAL CARGA MI MENU

<?php
session_start();
include '../php/conexion.php';
$dni=$_SESSION['id'];
$conexion=conexion();


if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
  if($_SESSION["tipo"]==1){?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Plantilla</title>

    </head>
    <body>
<div id="contenedorop" style="height:100%; width:100%">
            <div id="cabecera">
               
            </div>


  <div id="menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>      
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" id="datosusuario">Datos de Usuario<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>

      
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" id="ATMop" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Confeccionar ATM <span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="tpm">Tiempos de permanencia <br> en destinos de montaña</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="asc">Ascenciones</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="aiom">Actividades de instrucción <br> técnica operacional</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="titm">Tareas de instrucción <br> técnica operacional</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="rec">Reconocimientos</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="exi">Exigencias</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>          
        <li ><a href="#" id="verATM"> Ver ATM<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#" id="gc">Gestión Condor <br>Plateados<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
             
        <li ><a href="../php/logout.php">Salir<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>


      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>

        <div id="contenido" scroll=no></div>
        </div>

       

    </body>
</html>



 <script type="text/javascript">


            
            document.getElementById("rec").addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.querySelector("#contenido").innerHTML = '<object width="100%" height="90%" data="rec.php" ></object>';
            });
            document.getElementById("exi").addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.querySelector("#contenido").innerHTML = '<object width="100%" height="90%" data="exi.php" ></object>';
            });
            document.getElementById("gc").addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.querySelector("#contenido").innerHTML = '<object width="100%" height="90%" data="elevaratm.php" ></object>';
            });
            document.getElementById("verATM").addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.querySelector("#contenido").innerHTML = '<object width="100%" height="90%" data="../librerias/pdf/index.php" ></object>';
            });
           
            
            

        </script>

<?php
    }
?>
```

```html
ARCHIVO EXI.PHP llamado con uno de los item de menu cargado en el div contenido

<?php
 session_start();
 $nombreusuario=$_SESSION['user'];
  require_once "../php/conexion.php";
  $conexion=conexion();
?>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <h2>Exigencias</h2>
 <br>
  <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
  
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="1">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalexi" id="agregarnuevo" >Actualizar Aptitudes
    <span class="fi-plus"></span>
   </button>
  </td>
 </tr>
   

   <?php
    $sql ="SELECT e.exi_id,e.exi_esq_milbas, e.exi_esq_mil,e.exi_esq_subinst,e.exi_esq_instructor,e.exi_esc_milbas, e.exi_esc_mil,e.exi_esc_subinst,e.exi_esc_instructor,e.exi_calificacion  from c_usuarios u, c_exigencias e where  id_usr=u.usr_id and u.usr_user='$nombreusuario'";



    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql)or die($result. "<br/> error<br/>".mysql_error());


     while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

       $datos=$ver[0]."||".
         $ver[1]."||".
         $ver[2]."||".
         $ver[3]."||".
         $ver[4]."||".
         $ver[5]."||".
         $ver[6]."||".
         $ver[7]."||".
         $ver[8]."||".
         $ver[9];    
   ?> 
   

   <tr>
    <td><h4>Exigencias de Esquí</h4></td>
   </tr>
    <?php 
      if($ver[1]==1){
       printf("<tr><td>&nbsp;%s</td>","Esquiador Militar Básico");      
     ?>
    <?php  } ?>

    <?php 
      if($ver[2]==1){
       printf("<tr><td>&nbsp;%s</td>","Esquiador Militar");
     ?>
    <?php  } ?>

    <?php 
      if($ver[3]==1){
       printf("<tr><td>&nbsp;%s</td>","Subinstructor de Esquí");
     ?>
    <?php  } ?>

    <?php 
      if($ver[4]==1){
       printf("<tr><td>&nbsp;%s</td>","Instructor de Esquí");       
     ?>
    <?php  } ?>

   <tr>
    <td><h4>Exigencias de Andinismo</h4></td>
   </tr>
   
   

    
  
   
   <?php
  }
  
   ?>
  
  </table>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="rec.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modalnext">
     <span class="fi-chevron-left"></span>
            Atras
            
           </button><a>

            <a href="../php/controlaratm.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modalnext">
    
            Elevar aptitud condor
            
           </button><a>
           
           
        </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```html
Archivo CONTROLARATM.PHP llamado desde el boton ELEVAR APTITUD del archivo exi.php

<?php 
 session_start();
 $dni=$_SESSION['id'];
 require_once "conexion.php";
 $conexion=conexion();




// CONTROLAR EXIGENCIAS Y PES

$sqlexi ="SELECT e.exi_esq_milbas, e.exi_esq_mil,e.exi_esq_subinst,e.exi_esq_instructor,e.exi_esc_milbas, e.exi_esc_mil,e.exi_esc_subinst,e.exi_esc_instructor,e.exi_calificacion  
from c_usuarios u, c_exigencias e 
where u.usr_id=$dni and e.id_usr=u.usr_id";

$resultexi=mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlexi)or die($resultexi. "<br/> error<br/>".mysql_error());

$exiand=0;
$exiesq=0;
$exi=0;

    while($verexi = mysqli_fetch_row($resultexi)){
      $esq_milbas = $verexi[0];
      $esq_mil = $verexi[1];
      $esq_subinst = $verexi[2];
      $esq_instructor = $verexi[3];
      $esc_milbas = $verexi[4];
      $esc_mil = $verexi[5];
      $esc_subinst = $verexi[6];
      $esc_instructor = $verexi[7];
      $calificacion = $verexi[8];
    }
if(($esq_milbas==true) || ($esq_mil==true) || ($esq_subinst==true) || ($esq_instructor==true)){
 $exiesq=1;
}
if(($esq_milbas==true) || ($esq_mil==true) || ($esq_subinst==true) || ($esq_instructor==true)){
 $exiand=1;
}
if($calificacion >=80){
 $calif=1;
}

if($exiand==1 and $exiesq==1){
 $exi=1;
}




$mensaje="";


 if($exi==0){
  $mensaje +="Debe poseer al menos una EXIGENCIA de andinismo y una de esquí.\n";
 }
 if($calif==0){
  $mensaje+="Su calificación PES debe ser superior a 80 puntos.";
 }



 if($exi==1 && $calif==1){


 echo "<script type=''>
  alert('Solicitud Elevada');
  
  </script>";


 header('location: http://localhost/aptitudcondor/modulos/operaciones.php');

 }else{
  
  echo "<script type=''>
  alert('$mensaje');
  </script>"; 

  
 }

?>
```

Buenas tardes tengo este problema logre hacer el menú y al hacer click en sus opciones me llama las diferentes páginas de php en un div contenido.

El tema es el siguiente cuando le doy click a uno de los botonos que está cargado dentro de este div contenido que es el boton que finaliza la carga de los datos necesito actualizar mi página principal pero al hacerlo me recarga la página dentro de este div no se si me explico adjunto algunas imágenes. Hace ya dos semanas que estoy con esto.

[image: mi menu con la carga de una de sus opciones en el div contenido]

Cuando le doy al boton de elevar aptitud necesito recagar la página (para que se actalize el menú) lo hago con header location pero me queda de esta manera.

[image: el boton me recarga la pagina dentro del div que esta trabajando]

Comment: Deberías de poner el código que realiza las cargas de cada html

Comment: Ahi he colocado los tres archivos
1. Archivo principal que carga el menu          

2. Archivo exi.php llamado dentro del div contenido         

3. Archivo controlaratm.php que es llamado con el boton dentro del archivo exi.php y que recarga la pagina.

Comment: bueno finalmente encontre la solucion gracias!!!

window.parent.location.href='';